# I can see the concrete blocks inside the house through the paintwork

Tags: walls

in the lounge, I can see the outline of the concrete blocks behind the paintwork. Is this normal?

Comment: Many times the masonry is covered but some just paint it as a less expensive finish. I would say in most cases it is not normal unless a basement but not unheard of.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with simply leaving the cinder block surface and painting it.   It will look like painted cinder blocks.

It has a few advantages, it's tough, easier to clean, and *much, much, much, much* easier to clean up after a flood.

Covering that up with plaster or drywall is just a matter of aesthetics.  It's not like it's bad architecture, it's just a different design choice (of course the hooty-tooty crowd consider it more lowbrow, but whatever.)

If someone aimed to do that, and missed, then yeah, that's bad work.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not normal in homes in the US or UK and many other places.

Normally the structural elements of the wall would be lined on the inside surfaces using plaster, plasterboard/drywall or other materials to create a smooth uninterrupted surface.